# Why would the acoustic absorption coefficient of hexane in air be less than air?

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics

Why would the acoustic absorption coefficient of hexane in air be less than air? That is, a 120kHz pulse train shows a bigger amplitude after traveling in a hexane/air mix than in pure air?

My hypothesis is that the hexane molecule has fewer degree of freedom than that of N2/O2. Plausible?

Answer (score 0):

Best hypothesis so far is that as gas density increases the transducer couples more efficiently to the medium, giving the impression of a decrease in absorption coefficient due to the increased amplitude at the receiver.